# Why I can call Array.prototype.filter() on a object which is not an array?

Tags: javascript

```
filter    Creates a new array with all elements that pass
          the test implemented by the provided function.
```

---

```
>>> 'abc'.filter(function(e){return e!='b'})
TypeError: "abc".filter is not a function

>>> Array.prototype.filter.call('abc', function(e){return e!='b'})
["a", "c"]

>>> jQuery.isArray('abc')
false
```

Comment: No clue. `Array.filter` doesn't exist. Did you mean `Array.prototype.filter.call`?

Comment: @minitech `Array.filter` exists in Firefox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All array methods are generic; i.e., they work on any object with numeric properties plus a `length` property. See [the specification for `Array.prototype.filter`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.20), for example: note that the algorithm is phrased entirely in terms of things like

> Let `lenValue` be the result of calling the `[[Get]]` internal method of `O` with the argument `"length"`.

or

> Let `kPresent` be the result of calling the `[[HasProperty]]` internal method of `O` with argument `Pk`.

---

`Array.filter` is [a Firefox-specific extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.6#Array_and_String_generics), BTW. The cross-browser version is `Array.prototype.filter.call`.

Comment: I updated the note at the bottom, but yet I can't get String.filter to work in FF, so that part might not be accurate... or I completely missed what was trying to be said. Array.filter is per 5th Edition or JS 1.6... and `arr.filter` will work anywhere `Array.prototype.filter.call` works (String != Array). Anyway, hopefully this comment will reach you :)

Comment: `Array.filter` is not specified in ES5 spec. It's per JS 1.6, which is a Mozilla-specific extension. Removing edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this because `Array.filter`<sup>1</sup> is defined to be generic; you can call it on `NodeList`s, for example. This is just a convenience to the developer. It also works on strings, because in modern browsers (everything except IE 8 and earlier), you can access characters in a string like you would indices of an array, and that's what `filter` is based on, along with `length`:

```
var str = "Hello, world!";

str[2] // 'l'
```

However, I wouldn't recommend making use of this feature if you plan on supporting Internet Explorer 8 or earlier, because the ES5 shivs likely won't detect the fact that the context is a string, which will break things.

<sub><sup>1</sup> And all the other `Array` methods. Except, once again, on Internet Explorer 8 and earlier.</sub>

Comment: The most widely-used es5 shim (kriskowal/es5-shim) does in fact work correctly on non-array objects.